# C Arrays - Why is the last character in the array displaying, how do I get it to display only the first 5?

Tags: c

```
    /* Variables */
    int num;
    char array[5]; // Array must also include NULL char
    char new;

    /* Accepting user input */
    printf("Please enter 5 characters below:\n");
    scanf("%c\r", &array[0]);
    scanf("%c\r", &array[1]);
    scanf("%c\r", &array[2]);
    scanf("%c\r", &array[3]);
    scanf("%c", &array[4]);
    /* Displaying input as string */
    printf("%s", array);
```

I am trying to create a basic program that creates a string that accepts chars one after the other. I know that arrays start at 0 and end with the null character so I made my array[5] so if I inputted "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" I would get the output string "abcde" plus the null character. Sometimes it works with one set of characters but not another. If I input "q" "w" "e" "r" "t" i might get the output "qwerta". How do I stop it from displaying that last character?

I understand that the reason why this character being displayed is that it is undefined and will show whatever value is at that memory location but I don't know how to fix it.

I have tried to include different escape sequences, putting spaces in the scanf and printf statements but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you set the last character as `'\0'`?

Comment: char arrays only end with a null char if you leave enough space for one and put one in. It is not automatic, but is required to use it as a C style "string". `char array[5];` => `char array[6];`. `scanf("%c", &array[4]);` => `scanf("%c", &array[4]); array[5] = '\0';`

Comment: Oh right thank you that explains it, yeah i had it in my head that it was automatic

Comment: If you want to print the array content without needing a null character, you can change the line `printf("%s", array); ` to `printf("%.5s", array); `. That way, `printf` will not attempt to print more than 5 characters, so it won't attempt to read out of bounds of the array.

Comment: C is a very simple language, almost nothing is automatic.

Comment: `printf("%s", array);` fails as `"%s"` expects a matching _string_.

`array[]` is not a string as it lacks a _null character_.

To print the character array

    `printf("%.*s\n", 5, array);`

That will print the first 5 characters or up to a null character, which ever is first.

Answer (score 1):

You have a character array with size 5. You read a character into each of the five elements of the array. This does *not* leave space for the null character, and you do not explicitly set the last char equal to `'\0'`. Thus this is not a null terminated string, and printing it as a string with the `%s` specifier in `printf` has undefined behavior.